# mono - The name SqlContext does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin-studio

I've been successfully using a database migration tool for .NET called `DbUp` in my Windows projects for a long time, and I recently had to make sure it worked on Mono (under Mac OS X).

I downloaded the latest releases of Mono (4.4.1.0) and Xamarin (5.10.1.6) studio, but the project build fails at this line of code:

```
SqlContext.Pipe.Send("INFO:  " + string.Format(format, args));
```

The error is as follows:

> Engine/Output/SqlContextUpgradeLog.cs(9,13): error CS0103: The name
>   `SqlContext' does not exist in the current context

This code compiles perfectly fine on Windows using Visual Studio. I can see that `SqlContext` is a class contained in `System.Data.dll` assembly.
However, it seems to be missing in Mono.

Is this .NET class just not implemented in mono or do I have to take some additional steps to get it working?

Comment: `SqlContext` is specific to Windows, more precisely to SQL Server -- its namespace, after all, is `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server`. SQL Server does not run on many platforms supported by Mono.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, many other classes in `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server` namespace are present in mono. But `SqlContext` is missing for some reason, which seems weird.

Comment: I don't know what these many other classes are, but it makes little sense to provide support for a database server that does not run on your platform.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, the fact that SQL Server doesn't run on MacOS X doesn't mean that there shouldn't be a way for a Mac client to connect to a SQL Server instance running on Windows.

Comment: [There is a way to do that](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/database-access/providers/sqlclient/), but it is not built-in. You have to install and reference an external assembly.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, the link you provided says nothing about external assemblies. It just describes the way to connect to SQL Server using the standard .NET classes from `System.Data`.

Comment: It appears you're right. I was under the impression that `Mono.Data.Tds` was external, but it does look like it's part of Mono proper.